# How can I access private class members of container class within the anonymouse inner class?

Tags: java, swing, timer, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

How can I access all the member field of the class which contains the function initTimer() from within the AbstractActionClass?
Thanks

```
private void initTimer()
    {
       Action updateClockAction = new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    JLabel secLabel = m_GameApplet.GetJpanelStartNetGame().GetJlabelSeconds();
                    secLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Handwriting", 1, 36));
                    secLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
                    secLabel.setText(Integer.toString(m_TimerSeconds));
                    if(m_TimerSeconds >0)
                    {
                        m_TimerSeconds--;
                    }
                    else if (m_TimerSeconds == 0)
                    {
                        m_Timer.stop();
                        m_GameApplet.GetJpanelStartNetGame().GetJlabelSeconds().setText("0");
                        m_GameApplet.GetJpanelStartNetGame().GetJbuttonFinish().setVisible(false);
                        //Checking whether time ended for both players and no solution was recieved
                        if(!m_WasGameDecisived)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Tie - No one had a solution in the given time");
                            //askUserForAnotherRoundLeaveTableOrExitProgram();//////////////////////////////////////////////To implement
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            m_Timer = new Timer(1000, updateClockAction);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

```
ClassName.this.foo
```

where `foo` is a class member. For more information, see [JLS §15.8.4 Qualified this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#251603).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your outer class is called `OuterClass`, then `OuterClass.this.whatever`

Comment: Shouldn't even need to qualify it unless there is a collision.  Not that it's bad practice.

Comment: Very true. I tend to though, for clarity.